# Does JIRA support Tomcat 8?

Tags: java, tomcat, jira

I want to deploy JIRA on a Tomcat 8 instance I have. I've downloaded the WAR file from [here](https://www.atlassian.com/software/jira/download) and successfully built it.

When I try to deploy the WAR to Tomcat 7, it runs like a charm. But when  I try to deploy it on Tomcat 8, it gives an error and the JIRA service does not start up.  On the official site, documentation is available for Tomcat 6 and 7.

I want to know; does JIRA support Tomcat 8?

Answer (score 1):

[It doesn't.](https://confluence.atlassian.com/display/JIRA/Supported+Platforms)

The only currently supported version of Tomcat is **7.0.55**, with a few other caveats to it.

> - Deploying multiple Atlassian applications in a single Tomcat container is not supported. Please see Deploying Multiple Atlassian Applications in a Single Tomcat Container for reasons why we do not support this configuration.
> - Whilst JIRA may work with other versions of Apache Tomcat 6 & 7, it has not been tested on them and may cause problems. We recommend using these versions.

Comment: Assuming this answer was for JIRA 6.4 (the OP doesn't say). JIRA 7 does support Tomcat 8 according to your provided link.